Validate array of table names
I have requirement where bash script will pass on the string consisting tables names to anonymous PL/pgSQL block which will process the tables if they exists in the Postgres db.
Below is the PL/pgSQL code assuming given_tables variable has the string consisting table names provided through bash script.
do $do$
<<outerblock>>
declare
    tab text;
    given_tables text[] := ARRAY['ocab1.cust_docu_map','ocsbc2.cust_docu_map'];
    table_names  text[] := ARRAY(
                              BEGIN
                                FOREACH tab IN ARRAY given_tables loop
                                    IF EXISTS
                                        ( SELECT 1
                                          FROM pg_class
                                          WHERE oid = tab::regclass
                                        )
                                    THEN
                                          SELECT concat_ws('.',relnamespace::regnamespace::text,relname)
                                          FROM pg_class
                                          WHERE oid = tab::regclass
                                          AND relreplident != 'f';
                                    END IF;
                                END LOOP;
                              END
                            );
begin
  foreach table in array table_names loop
    raise notice 'here is the table - %',outerblock.table;  
  end loop;
end $do$;

But code errors out:

ERROR:  mismatched parentheses at or near ";"
LINE 18:             AND relreplident != 'f';
                                            ^


Not sure where I am going wrong?

Pretty sure you cannot use plpgsql constructs inside an ARRAY(), Why not just pull that LOOP out of ARRAY() and do raise notice 'here is the table - %' in the loop.

But I need to array to process the final list of tables which does exists in the db after validation. Please guide

DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _given_tbls text[] := '{ocab1.cust_docu_map,ocsbc2.cust_docu_map}';
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT format('%I.%I', n.nspname, c.relname)         -- properly quoted
      FROM   unnest(_given_tbls) t(tbl)
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.oid = to_regclass(t.tbl)  -- does not raise exception
      JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  c.relreplident != 'f'
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'valid table: %', _tbl;  
      -- or do something here!
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;

to_regclass(_tab) does not raise an exception for invalid table names. See:

How to check if a table exists in a given schema

Remember that identifiers stored in catalog tables may need double-quoting. Quote with format() or quote_ident() to defend against syntax errors or even SQL injection attacks.
regclass values are quoted automatically when converted to text, but only schema-qualified when necessary with the current search_path. You seem to want fully qualified names. See:

Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter

Also, it's much cheaper to run a single query and loop through results (if you really need to loop at all?), than to run another query (or even two!) for every element in the array.

Thanks for to_regclass(), didn't know that function. Thanks!

That code is not valid, you can't construct an array like that. And you don't need it either, just execute the query to get the tables from pg_class. Something like this:
DO
$do$
    DECLARE
        given_tables TEXT[] = ARRAY ['ocab1.cust_docu_map','ocsbc2.cust_docu_map'];
        _tab          TEXT;
        _row         RECORD;
    BEGIN
        FOREACH _tab IN ARRAY given_tables
            LOOP
                FOR _row IN
                    SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', relnamespace::REGNAMESPACE::TEXT, relname) AS t
                    FROM pg_class
                    WHERE oid = _tab::REGCLASS -- error when table doesn't exist!
                      AND relreplident != 'f'
                    LOOP
                        RAISE NOTICE 'here is the table - %', _row.t;
                    END LOOP;
            END LOOP;
    END
$do$;

Be careful, this query fails with an error when you look for a table that doesn't exist. You'd better query for the relname and schema name. In that case you just don't get a result.
